# Error when trying to fix "unmet dependencies" on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install php5-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

But I got this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-contrib-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-9.3 (= 9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04) but 9.3.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But then I get this error:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
 * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 255.
Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 264.
(does not shutdown gracefully, now stopping immediately)

[fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.3_9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.3_9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My config:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I have no idea how to fix this... Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It fails to stop, so try to stop it manually:

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

Make sure that apt cache is up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Try again to fix:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If it doesn't work, wipe postgresql completely. See, what postgresql packages are installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep postgresql
```

Then, remove with `sudo apt-get remove <package name>`. Pay attention to the messages like "THE FOLLOWING PACKAGES WILL BE REMOVED", don't accept if important stuff is listed there.

Try once more to fix:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `postgresql-9.3` in `trusty main` is `9.3.7-0ubuntu0.14.04`. To install `9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04` you need `trusty-updates main`.

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and check if you have enabled the `trusty-updates` repository at least for `main`

eg:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe
```

---

Results from the [Ubuntu packages search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=postgresql-9.3)

```
Paket postgresql-9.3

    trusty (14.04LTS) (database): object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
    9.3.7-0ubuntu0.14.04 [security]: amd64 i386
    trusty-updates (database): object-relational SQL database, version 9.3 server
    9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04: amd64 i386
```